# SP16 - How to add metatag in header of sharepoint list page(EditForm and NewForm) with SPD

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, spfx

I want to add following code in my page where is SPFx web part:

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
</asp:Content>
```

[image]